# I need a regx to validate a name that can be 1, 2, or 3 words

Tags: regex

In this example I try to validate for a city name.  It works if I enter San Louis Obispo but not if I enter Boulder Creek or Boulder.  I thought ? was supposed to make a block optional.

```
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z'-]+\s[a-zA-Z'-]*\s([a-zA-Z']*)?$/.test(field)){
        return "Enter City only a-z A-Z .\' allowed and not over 20 characters.\n";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think spaces are the problem (\s). You made second and third words optional (by using * instead of +), but not the spaces. Question mark is only being applied to the third word because of parentheses.

Comment: Brilliant!  That's it all I had to do is put the question marks after the spaces.  Thank you!

Comment: np :) note that you probably don't want word and space to be optional independently - put them in a group. FYI RegexBuddy is a nice tool for fiddling with Regex expressions; it might also help to write unit tests for various scenarios: different number of words, spaces / no spaces, capitalization, etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your regex is that, in english, it says to match a word that's required to be followed by a space that's optionally followed by another word but then is required to have another space and then optionally another word. So, a single-word would not match - however, a word followed by two spaces would. Additionally two words that have a space at the end would also match - but neither without the trailing spaces would match.

To fix your exact regex you should add another grouping (non-matching group with `(?:` instead of just `(`) around the second word to the end of the sentence) and have this group as optional with `?`. Also, move the `\s`'s inside the optional groups as well.

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z'-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z'-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z']+)?)?$
```

Regex explaind:

```
^                           # beginning of line
    [a-zA-Z'-]+             # first matching word
    (?:                     # start of second-matching word
        \s[a-zA-Z'-]+       # space followed by matching word
        (?:                 # start of third-matching word
            \s[a-zA-Z']+    # space followed by matching word
        )?                  # third-matching word is optional
    )?                      # second-matching word is optional
$                           # end of line
```

Alternatively, you can try the following regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z'-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2})$
```

This will match 1 through 3 words, or "cities", in a given line with the ability to adjust the range of words without having to further-duplicate the matching set for each new word.

Regex explained:

```
^(                            # start of line & matching group
    [a-zA-Z'-]+               # required first matching word
    (?:                       # start a non-matching group (required to "match", but not returned as an individual group)
        \s                    # sub-group required to start with a space
        [a-zA-Z'-]+           # sub-group matching word
    ){0,2}                    # sub-group can match 0 -> 2 times
)$                            # end of matching group & line
```

So, if you want to add the ability to match more than 3 words, you can change the `2` in the `{0,2}` range above to be the number of words you want to match minus 1 (i.e. if you want to match 4 words, you'll set it to `{0,3}`).